# Regular expression and AwkFilenameFilter

Tags: java, regex, apache

We have a folder where we dump lot of files. Our program needs to read one of the specific files with the latest version. The file name would be something like "**2016-03-04-12-46-48_ABC_123456_1.xml**".

Insted of reading all the files and then iterating to find the exact file i have used following code with a regular expression

```
File folder = new File("C:\\some_folder")    
folder.listFiles((FilenameFilter) new AwkFilenameFilter("(\\d){4}-(\\d){2}-(\\d){2}-(\\d){2}-(\\d){2}-(\\d){2}_ABC_" + <ID_String> +"_(\\d){1,2}"))
```

But for some reason the reqular expression is not working. Can someone please help with this?

Comment: Can you elaborate on `is not working`?  Which files does it currently match, or nothing at all?  Could the `AwkFilenameFilter` class use its own flavor of regex (you have use Java style regex)?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen: it does not match any file

Comment: @NayanSonthalia: Are you getting any errors or it is just that it is not listing any files?

Comment: @AKS: no errors. It is just not displaying any files.

Comment: Don't you also need to include the file extension in the regex?

Comment: @AKS: +1 for this.. Thanks.. that saved me.. Please post this as an answer and i will accept it... Either i was being foolish or i was missing the basics... thanks again

Comment: Thanks. I posted my comment in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are missing the file extension in the regex:

```
(\\d){4}-(\\d){2}-(\\d){2}-(\\d){2}-(\\d){2}-(\\d){2}_ABC_" + <ID_String> +"_(\\d){1,2}\\.xml
```

Comment: Yes the missing thing was file extension. Thanks again. This might be of help to someone in future.

Answer (score 0):

Try out this one.

```
"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}_ABC_"+<ID string>+"_\d{1}.xml"
```

It works perfectly for me.

Comment: Regular expression that is fromed is not matching with any file.. Probably something to do with AckFilenameFilter.. I dont have any idea on how it works so dont know what type of regular expression it will take. I created a java expression which is failing

Comment: @Nayan just bind the .xml extension at the end of the regex because I tested it